# ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) - VSCode

Tags: python

I'm new to coding, and I am currently learning Python through real world examples given to me by the software engineers I work with. The objective here is to revise the code to check for image similarities for IR images. So far, I have been able to resolve most issues and fix minor errors on my own, until I reached this error message.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\xxxxx\Documents (This PC)\VSCode\projects\image_compare.py in line 46
     44 img_path = os.path.join(path,img)
     45 #test_img = cv2.imread(img_path)
---> 46 gnum = get_gnum(img)
     47 base_image = []
     48 base_image.append(img_path)

c:\Users\xxxxx\Documents (This PC)\VSCode\projects\image_compare.py in line 20, in get_gnum(path)
     18 def get_gnum(path):
     19     split_underline = path.split('_')[0]
---> 20     return int(split_underline)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '--ip=127.0.0.1'
```

Here is the whole code for reference (changed path information for privacy reasons):

```
# %%
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sys import argv
from image_similarity_measures.quality_metrics import fsim, ssim


def sort_num(path):
    split_folder = path.split('\\')[-1]
    #print(split_folder)
    split_underline = split_folder.split('_')[-1]
    #print(split_ubderline)
    return int(split_underline[0:-4])

def get_gnum(path):
    split_underline = path.split('_')[0]
    return int(split_underline)

def compare(or_imgs, test_img):
    Use = False
    similarity = 0
    ssim_measures = {}
    test = cv2.imread(test_img)#,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGE)
    #test = test.astype(np.int64)
    #print(len(or_imgs))
    for or_img in or_imgs:
        original = cv2.imread(or_img)#, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGE)
        #original = original.astype(np.int64)
        #print(or_img, test_img)
        ssim_measures[or_img] = ssim(test, original)
    if max(ssim_measures.values()) < 0.94:
        or_imgs.append(test_img)
        Use = True
        print(test_img, 'score', max(ssim_measures.values()))
    return Use, or_imgs


path = '/yyy/xxxx_zz/Annotation_footage_1hz'

img = argv[1]
img_path = os.path.join(path,img)
#test_img = cv2.imread(img_path)
gnum = get_gnum(img)
base_image = []
base_image.append(img_path)
ssim_measures = {}
#fsim_measures = {}

#scale_percent = 100 # percent of original img size
#width = int(test_img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
#height = int(test_img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
#dim = (width, height)

#data_dir = 'data
comp_img_path = os.path.join(path,'%d_*.bmp' %gnum)
file_list = glob.glob(comp_img_path)
file_list.sort(key=sort_num)
#print(file_list[0:2])
for file in file_list:
    #img_path = os.path.join(data_dir, file)
    #print(file)
    #data_img = cv2.imread(file)
    Use, base_image = compare(base_image, file)
print(len(base_image))
    #resized_img = cv2.resize(data_img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
        
        #fsim_measures[file]= fsim(test_img, resized_img)

def calc_closest_val(dict, checkMax):
    result = {}
    if (checkMax):
        closest = max(dict.values())
    else:
        closest = min(dict.values())
            
    for key, value in dict.items():
        print("The difference between ", key ," and the original image is : \n", value)
    if (value == closest):
            result[key] = closest
            
    print("The closest value: ", closest)       
    print("######################################################################")
    return result
    
#ssim = calc_closest_val(ssim_measures, True)
#fsim = calc_closest_val(fsim_measures, True)

#print("The most similar according to SSIM: " , ssim)
#print("The most similar according to fsim: " , fsim)

# %%
```

I have tried a few things, like changing the environment to (base) Conda, adding and removing quotation marks, changing "int(split_underline)" to "int(split_underline[0]), and so far nothing has worked. I have also scoured other questions with this same error message and none of them seem to provide solid solutions for this.

I can only guess that something with defining "gnum" and "get_gnum" is causing this issue? I've tried playing around with combinations of "img_path", "path", "img", etc. and I still can't understand the issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're putting a string into an int variable. Its a string that cannot be converted to an int

Comment: If you trying to get a directory name, I wouldn't worry about covnerting anything to an int

Comment: Python is telling you that the string `'--ip=127.0.0.1'` is not a number, and cannot be converted to an integer with `int()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a site for specific questions, but this isn't a question, and it's not clear what you need help with exactly. It seems like you don't even understand what the error message is saying, so I think you should learn some more before tackling this project. Or you could ask the software engineers for help. To learn how to use this site better, see [ask] for tips like making a [mre] (I'd want to see how you're calling the script). See also [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

The function `split()` well, split the string at the given caracter.
For example, this code :

```
path = "this/is/a/path/for/the/file_14"
out = path.split("_")
print(out)
```

will return the following list
`['this/is/a/path/for/the/file', '14']`

Therefore, you could do `int(out[1])` because, well, you can convert `'14'` to `14`
But `int(out[0])` will raise an error.

So maybe your img filename is not in `argv[1]` but in `argv[2]` ? (This is a common mistake because `argv[0]` is the name of the program, and not the first argument)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you run the script with a command along the lines of :

```
python image_compare.py --ip=127.0.0.1 ...
```

When in your code you do `img = argv[1]` you set the value of img to `--ip=127.0.0.1`

Later, when you call the `get_gnum(img)` function, you try to spit the string `--ip=127.0.0.1` on the `_` character since it doesn't have one it returns an array with the full string. Then you try to convert this full string to a number, and it won't work since the string `--ip=127.0.0.1` isn't a number.

From what I can see, later in the code (`'%d_*.bmp'`) I think that you expect a filename in the format `number_anything.bmp`. So you should either replace the `--ip=17.0.0.1` parameter in your command with such a file or change the `argv[1]` to `argv[x]` if you do pass the filename in the command but not as the first argument of the script.